# how to trigger a downstream pipeline on a tagged branch in gitlab multi project pipeline?

Tags: gitlab, gitlab-ci

I would like to trigger a GitLab project, but instead of using a branch, I would like to use a specific tag. How can this be achieved?

The following triggers the `develop` branch of `some-project`:

```
bridge:
  stage: bridge
  trigger:
    project: some-project
    branch: develop
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use the parent-child pipeline feature with the `ref` keyword, like this:

```
bridge:
  stage: bridge
  trigger:
    include:
      - project: some-project
        ref: 'your-tag'
        file: '.gitlab-ci.yml'
```

Comment: @Glen_Thomas I think using include makes the second pipeline a child pipeline.

Answer (score 0):

You can trigger the pipeline using the API.

Example using a curl command, which you can add to your job script:

```
curl --request POST --form "token=$CI_JOB_TOKEN" --form ref=my-tag \
  https://gitlab.example.com/api/v4/projects/6/trigger/pipeline
```

When you use the `CI_JOB_TOKEN` to trigger pipelines, GitLab recognises the source of the job token. The pipelines become related, so you can visualise their relationships on pipeline graphs.